# Push database to docker container using Docker compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, linux-mint

Tell me how to throw the database into the docker container.

Database - MongoDB

I use these docker compose settings

```
    version: '3'

services:
  main_front_2:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./main_front_2.0
    container_name: main-front-2
    depends_on:
      - main_back
      - main_auth_back
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  main_back:
    build: ./main_back
    container_name: main-back
    command: npm run start
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - main_back_db

  main_auth_back:
    build: ./main_auth_back
    container_name: main-auth-back
    command: npm run start
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - main_back_db

  main_back_db:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: main-back-db
    volumes:
      - mongodb_back:/var/lib/mongodb

volumes:
  mongodb_back:
```

From the application I connect using this address:

```
mongodb://main_back_db:27017/authopenschool
```

After that I go to docker exec and the databases in the container are empty

please tell me what i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

mongo db data is stored in `/data/db` path. 
fixed version:

```
main_back_db:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: main-back-db
    volumes:
      - mongodb_back:/data/db
```

to check it, you can inspect container:

```
docker exec -it main-back-db bash
mongo
```

then `show dbs` or `show collections`

Comment: @Андрей Степанов does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My mongodb data is stored along the path: /var/lib/mongodb
I tried to make the usual path instead of the named volume and before running docker compose removed the containers. Everything worked